# do I have to release the NSDate in this code below?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks, profiling, nsdate

do I have to release the NSDate in this code below?

(i.e. or is it the case that it's just created within a method as a local variable that I don't have to worry)

The reason I ask is when I run XCode Profiler and click on one of the points where memory is jumping up, it highligted this bit of code (i.e. the first line in the attached code below) - i.e. I'm looking at the "Leaks Blocks" table in the profiler..

```
-(NSDate *) dateBySettingHour:(NSInteger)hour andMinute:(NSInteger)minute {

    // Get Calendar for Existing Date
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components: NSUIntegerMax fromDate: self];

    // Set Hour and Minute
    [components setHour: hour];
    [components setMinute: minute];
    [components setSecond: 00];

    // Create resultant Date
    NSDate *newDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents: components];    // WHERE THE PROFILE HIGHLIGHTS

    // Clean Up
    [gregorian release];    

    return newDate;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to release the `NSDate` object returned by `-[NSCalendar dateFromComponents:]`. <strike>My guess is that the line was highlighted as it was the last time you referenced `components` (an instance of `NSDateComponents`, hopefully) and you forgot to release *that* object.</strike>

Your code is fine. When I run the static analyser (rather than the profiler), it reports no errors. I am not sure why the profiler would report a leak -- perhaps there's an internal leak in the Cocoa framework?

Comment: Oh - I've put the full method in the post now - based on this do you think it would be the components variable? (I didn't produce it with an alloc or copy)

Comment: @Greg: I've updated my answer. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: ok thanks - perhaps I'll post a separate focused question re why the profiler is highlighting this code if it is in fact ok

Answer (score 2):

No you don't have to release it. It is autoreleased.

Comment: just wondering why then the profiler highlighted this line to me Tom I guess