# do the entries in the XCode profiler "Leaked Blocks" table imply there was definite leakage?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, memory-leaks, profiler

do the entries in the XCode profiler "Leaked Blocks" table imply there was definite leakage?

That is assuming I run my iPhone app under profiler, than look at the leaked blocks information.  so there are multiple NSDate rows at the top of my list.  If I click on one of these rows I can navigate down to the bit of code in question.

So I'm wanting to confirm do all instances of entries in the "Leaked Blocks" table imply there is a real leakage there, that requires coding to be updated/fixed to resolve?

NOTE - One of the reasons I ask is that the code I posted here [do I have to release the NSDate in this code below?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092482/do-i-have-to-release-the-nsdate-in-this-code-below) for example was from code that the profiler highed to me under "Leaked Blocks", however the code (refer to this post) was reviewed by others and they tell me it's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do the entries in the XCode profiler "Leaked Blocks" table imply there was definite leakage?

yes.

leaks are evaluated in a lazy manner. leaks is not guaranteed to catch all leaks because it does not actually record all references - it just scans the process's memory (including stacks and registers) for patterns (e.g. the pointer value) of active allocations.

`man leaks` will give you specifics of the implementation, and the WEAKNESSES section confirms my response to your question, and gives an example of a circumstance where leaks will not be detected.

if you manage your allocations in a truly convoluted way (e.g. pointer arithmetic/offsets), you could in fact work around the system and introduce false positives -- don't do that =)

when you post code at SO and people tell you it's right, they mean the program you *posted* is correct - the leak (reference count imbalance in this case) is introduced in *another* part of your program. that is, the pointer you return (`newDate` in the link) is not correctly ref-counted by the caller, or who the caller passes it to.

instruments all record all ref counts for you - in case static analysis returns no issues.

specifically, instruments is showing you where the leaked allocation/object was *created*.

hope that helps.

Comment: thanks Justin - so basically I should be looking at any methods that called the method and got the NSDate back and what they did with it then?

Comment: @Greg exactly. it's the client/caller of `-(NSDate *) dateBySettingHour:(NSInteger)hour andMinute:(NSInteger)minute` (from the referenced link) that is introducing the imbalance in the reference count. either the caller, or whatever else the caller that receives `newDate` passes the allocation to. instruments can record every ref count during an object's lifetime, and record the traces - very very useful if the program is complex.

Comment: @Justin - ok, so in this case (given the method code is ok & I think the NSDate created is already autoreleased? I think??), then would be looking for a calling party who treated the NSDate as if it wasn't already auto-released then?

Comment: @Greg exactly (more characters required)

Comment: @Justin - last question I think - so this memory leak condition wouldn't be picked up by an ANALYZE then?  (i.e. it seems like Analyze does pick memory issues up for me when I use it)

Comment: @Greg it is in fact *possible* that the static analyzer will flag it at the callsite - and it will flag this mistake when the conditions are right. for a number of reasons, static analysis is not guaranteed to flag it as a leak (an obvious example: the new date is assigned to an object's ivar). static analysis takes hints from naming conventions to detect external imbalances for returned objects. the message would be along the lines of: *look: you received an autoreleased object, then retained it here, then the pointer went out of scope here*. but there's no guarantee that it will be flagged.